# gcc via homebrew has no --without-multilib option

Tags: macos, python-3.x, gcc, anaconda, xgboost

I want to install xgboost in Python 3.5. This requires gcc to support `-fopenmp` option. Default gcc does not support it. So I am using

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

But I get `Warning: gcc: this formula has no '--without-multilib' option so it will be ignored!` Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

[The option no longer exists, since 8/2017](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/16751). Many older 3rd-party xgboost instructions are outdated. Just do `brew install gcc` without options and be amazed that everything still works.