# Fixing gcc version used for python/anaconda packages

Tags: python, gcc, anaconda, xgboost, lightgbm

I wanted to install xgboost in Python 3.5. This requires gcc to support -fopenmp option. Default gcc does not support it. So I tried via brew but it did not work with latest gcc version

[gcc via homebrew has no --without-multiliboption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263504/gcc-via-homebrew-has-no-without-multiliboption)

So I installed gcc@5 which worked and I could install xgboost.

Then I wanted to install lightgbm which I did via pip install. But when I loaded it I got the following error:

```
OSError: dlopen(//anaconda/envs/python3p5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/7/libgomp.1.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/envs/python3p5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
  Reason: image not found
```

It is some how looking for gcc7 which is not there.

How can I fix the gcc version for an anaconda environment?